# Add another transition to a currently running transition

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Assume I have a chart with vertical bars that change their height using a D3 transition (1st transition). Now I need to add another transition (be it fill color change) to existing one, for example, when I mouseover on a bar that is currently changing its size (2nd transition).

Now if I do a mouseover, the 1st transition stops running leaving a bar in the middle of its way, beginning and running 2nd transition.

I want the bar to keep growing and meanwhile change its color in another transition.

How can I perform it?

Comment: Check if a transition is currently running (`.__transition__` member) before attaching the new one.

Comment: Is this still relevant? 
I see only `__data__`, `__onclick__`, `__onmouseenter__`, `__onmousemove__`, `__onmouseleave__` special objects there for a selection.

Comment: Well this is the way to check whether a transition is already running. You may also find [this post](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/) helpful.